# Rename using a part file name

Tags: php

Please bear with me as I have very limited programming knowledge (Some would say enough to be a danger. I delve into the odd PHP scripts for small jobs.

Now I have just installed an IP camera that out puts snapshot files such as:

```
192.168.0.108_01_20140718125232_TIMING.jpg
192.168.0.108_01_20140720123838_TIMING.jpg
192.168.0.108_01_20140718135321_TIMING.jpg
```

And so on these are generated every 15 mins or so.

Now as you can see most of the file name is the same but the time is amended for each snapshot, which I cant change in the camera.

I need a simple PHP script to find one of the snapshots (Anyone in fact as there will only be one in the folder at any one time) based on part of the stable file name and rename it to:

```
IBAYOFPL32.jpg
```

so the next image that comes from the camera in the long format will in turn be renamed and the IBAYOFPL32.jpg overwritten with the new one. So I need the script to loop as well so the whole thing ticks over on its own.

I have been searching for days finding similar scripts which can in fact rename the long file name to the one I want but you have to have the full correct file name of the long version to make it run as the file name changes with time.

I really hope this all makes sense if not please let me know.

Im using: Apache version    2.2.25
PHP version     5.2.17

The server directory the images are created in is:

```
/home/blue19/public_html/cams
```

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: If there is only one in the folder does the camera remove any others, and if so and I'm assuming you need to change the name for something else to view it, you could just make that work using htaccess. It might be worth adding the reason why it needs to be that name, because you might find a solution that isn't based upon the only way you think it's possible.

Comment: No the camera just keeps adding each snapshot at the specified time intervals, the file name I'm changing it to has to be that for another website that reads that directory to grab the next image and its always looking for www.blue19.com/cams/IBAYOFPL32.jpg

Comment: And yes your right, the solution might be very different to what I think it may work, I'm open to suggestions :-)

Comment: Well you don't need a cron job to do what you want to do, if all you need is the most recent image to appear when requesting IBAYOFPL32.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that the image changes every 15 minutes, so you will have to rename it every 15 minutes, so that means the script of renaming it should be executed in every 15 minutes automatically. This can be done by Cron Tab.

Coming to renaming part:
Put this php file outside cams folder:

```
    <?php
    Func_rename('IBAYOFPL32.jpg');

    function Func_rename($renametothis)
    {
    $dir='cams';
    $file = scandir($dir);
    $screenshotname=$file[2]; //assuming there is only screenshot in the cams folder (even if there are more than one, it will find the one in alphabetic as well as numeric order)
    rename ($dir.'/'.$screenshotname,$dir.'/'.$renametothis);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I ran that above code from  user1735921 and got back:Fatal error: Cannot redeclare rename() in /home/blue19/public_html/file.php on line 13

Comment: Re://assuming there is only screenshot in the cams folder (even if there are more than one, it will find the one in alphabetic order)  ththe long filenames only differ in time value Numeric not Alpha

Comment: It will check for numeric value too.
I have updated the code, this will work and do it.

Comment: Sorry I did not see the part of the comment that mentioned it will look for numerical seq as well. :-)

Comment: I just ran it again and it seems to be working now .... I will do some more testing and keep you posted.

Comment: Well all seems to be working well, I just have to sort out the CRON timer now, I think I can manage that part, Fantastic and thanks for your help (Both of you). That will save some of my hair !!!!!

Comment: script works fine but having trouble getting to run via CRON: Minute Hour Day Month Weekday Command Actions * * * * * /home/blue19/public_html/file.php > /dev/null im just running it every minut to see if it works, but it does not change the file name via CRON it does via WWW. –

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = 'IBAYOFPL32.jpg';
if ($data = glob('/home/blue19/public_html/cams/*_TIMING.jpg'))
{
    arsort($data); // order by timestamp, most recent image goes first
    unlink($name); // delete old IBAYOFPL32.jpg
    rename(array_unshift($data), $name); // rename most recent image to IBAYOFPL32.jpg
    while ($file = array_unshift($data)) unlink($file); // delete other images, we don't need them anyway do we?
}
```

Comment: Can you make this a script that will run for me I tried <?php bits but it would not run sorry, That's how little I know, I can sometimes play around with scripts when they are complete.

Comment: user1735921 script works fine but having trouble getting to run via CRON:  Minute  Hour  Day  Month  Weekday  Command  Actions
*  *  *  *  *  /home/blue19/public_html/file.php > /dev/null    im just running it every minut to see if it works, but it does not change the file name via CRON it does via WWW.

Comment: You can't run PHP from console just by giving the file name like that, you have to use `php /home/blue19/public_html/file.php`

Comment: Ah thanks for that, Its a fast learning curve, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Its working just as I want it to ! perfect, again thanks for you help guys  :-)